# When i learned about useReducer hook, i don't figure it out the difference between Switch and If on Reducer Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, switch-statement

i'm studying useReducer hook with simple Login UI.

In Login.js

```
const [passwordState, dispatchPassword] = useReducer(passwordReducer, {
  value: "",
  isValid: null,
});
```

first, passwordReducer function is below. however this code cannot change state.

```
const passwordReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PASSWORD_INPUT":
     return { value: action.val, isVaild: action.val.trim().length > 6 };

    case "PASSWORD_ONBLUR":
     return { value: state.value, isValid: state.value.trim().length > 6 };

    default:
     return { value: "", isValid: false };
  }
}
```

second, below similar IF code.

```
const passwordReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "PASSWORD_INPUT") {
    return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.trim().length > 6 };
  }
  if (action.type === "PASSWORD_ONBLUR") {
    return { value: state.value, isValid: state.value.trim().length > 6 };
  }
  return { value: "", isValid: false };
};
```

this code works well.

i don't know why first case cannot work, second case works well..

i attached codesandbox link below.

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-rosalind-mtjbsz?file=/src/components/Login/Login.js)

Please looking at Login.js
I don't know the difference.. thank you.

Comment: You've got a typo in the switch statement: `isVaild:` should read `isValid:`

Comment: Thank you for finding typo error! now it s working:)

Answer (score 0):

you got typo in:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case "PASSWORD_INPUT":
     return { value: action.val, isVaild: action.val.trim().length > 6 };
```

`isVaild:` should read `isValid:`